# How can I make my python discord bot not reply to the ephemeral message I have it make?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having trouble setup a /say command with my own bot, well I have it working it just replies to the ephemeral message which kinda defeats the purpose of the command. I do want to keep it a hybrid command so that I can still use the prefix command.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzHuU.png)

```
@bot.hybrid_command(name = "say", with_app_command=True, description="Sends a message in the channel")
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id=1171148231460265984))
@commands.has_any_role("owner", "admin") 
async def say(ctx, message: str):
    if ctx.interaction is not None:
        await ctx.send("Message sent successfully!", ephemeral=True, reference=None)
    else:
        await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(message, reference=None)
```

[It replying to the ephemeral command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzHuU.png)

I'm just hoping for some help so that it won't reply to the ephemeral message and I feel like I've already searched everywhere for help.